# Proper jump host configuration on AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

We have an AWX that needs to run playbooks on all servers within our lab.
There are some servers that can't be contacted unless using a bastion.
AWX can successfully run playbooks on the regular servers, but can't do it using jump host.
I will call the server that playbook will be run on it, client. Bastion will be referring to the server in the middle to connect to client.
The way I have it set up is that I have a set of username/password for the client that is saved as machine credentials in AWX.
I also have a custom credential type created as follow:
**Input configuration**

```
fields:
  - id: hostname
    type: string
    label: Jump server hostname
  - id: username
    type: string
    label: Jumphost username
  - id: sshkey
    type: string
    label: Bastion key.
    format: ssh_private_key
    secret: true
    multiline: true
required:
  - username
  - sshkey
  - hostname
```

**Injector configuration**

```
extra_vars:
  bastion_host: '{{ hostname }}'
  bastion_key: '{{ tower.filename }}'
  bastion_user: '{{ username }}'
  jumpserver_connection_configuration: >-
    -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -o
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes  -o
    ControlMaster=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -i {{ tower.filename }} -W %h:%p -q {{ username }}@{{ hostname }}"
file:
  template: '{{ sshkey }}'
```

Then there is an inventory created that has IP of the client and below extra args:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: >-
  {{ default_ssh_options }} -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey,password {{ jumpserver_connection_configuration }}
default_ssh_options: >-
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  -o
  PubkeyAuthentication=yes  -o ControlMaster=no -o
  PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```

A hello world job is created on this inventory with both credentials attached to it, which fails
The failure log is uploaded [here](https://jmp.sh/gpifIOd5).